# Not finding function using GetProcAddress() C++ VBexpress 13

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

Okay so I'm coming dangerously close to a repost here but my situation is a little bit different than the numerous other posters about this function. I am interfacing with a DLL that was written way back in the day and all I have is the file. I don't have a .lib file so I'm using the LoadLibrary and GetProcessAddress functions. I followed the tutorial on the MSDN website to get the basic structure. the DLL is located in the project folder. it compiles. at run time, I am getting a numerical value for "hinstLib" so I'm assuming the DLL was found. I am getting a null value for "ProcAdd" variable. Other posters had there issues resolved by putting extern C in the DLL functions but I don't really have that option. not to mention, to my knowledge this DLL was written in plain C.  I do have an interface document and am quite sure I have the function name correct (replaced with a generic example for these purposes). I honestly didn't run anything past the ProcAdd assignment because it came out NULL. Any thoughts as to why this is giving me a 0 value for the function assignment would be great appreciated. Note: unfortunately due to various reasons I can't upload the DLL.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Windows.h"
    #include <stdio.h> 

    typedef int(__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR);

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      HINSTANCE hinstLib;
      MYPROC ProcAdd;
      BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

      hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dllName.dll"));
      if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
    ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "funcName"); 

    // If the function address is valid, call the function.

    if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
    {
        fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
        //(ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); 
    }
    // Free the DLL module.

    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
} 

// If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
    printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your problem is the function name, which you have cleverly replaced with a made-up thing in the code above.

Comment: Side note: `#include "stdafx.h"` should appear before all other `#include` statements IIRC.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of... looks like I'm on my own on this one then. Thanks for assistance guys.

Comment: you're not on your own but you're not helping those who could help you, instead placing barriers in their way. :( now, try `dumpbin /exports blahblah.dll` and check the name(s) of the function. By the way, 2 problems with your code. You have a precompiled header not first, which means everything before it is ignored. Second, you're using Microsoft `TEXT` macros for pre-2000 compatibility with MFC in DLL for Windows 9x (phew), that's not realistic. You can just ditch all the `T` stuff.

Comment: wow that's a great tool. I ran it on the DLL, the file names in my interface document were not specific enough. It works now. Now as a followup question... I did the exact same thing again and command prompt gave me an error of "invalid file format; ignored". do I have to close the DLL or something?

Comment: that sounds like a non-DLL file (more generally, a non-PE format file).

Comment: please disregard that last question. I figured it out. thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: So not sure what the protocol is on asking a tacked on question onto the back of a post but I figured it was worth a shot if you guys were willing to help out. When I hit the line '(ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); ' I get the error _Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention._ I changed the LPWSTR in 'typedef int(__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR);' to char* because that is fnc input

Comment: according to some other posts, this error is due to reference errors. I have reason to believe it is due to my char array inputs. Which would you suspect would be the issue? my understanding of LPWSTR might be a bit off. I'm doing some research into that side but the debugging tool isn't really giving me any details. Thank you for the continued service and support on this question

Answer (score 1):

Compilers usually mangle function names, then a function named `funcName` may appear inside the DLL with a name `funcName@16` , for example... It depends on calling convention and are important for a function to be called properly. For `__cdecl` calling convention you probably need `_funcName` :-) .